# When do we use $\boldsymbol\tau=I \boldsymbol\alpha$ and $\boldsymbol\tau=\mathbf r \times \mathbf F $? Is the answer to both comes the same?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, moment-of-inertia

Is the torque of a body about an axis and the torque due to a force at a distance the same thing? Is the torque at a point by a force equal to the torque of the whole body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation
$$\boldsymbol\tau=\mathbf r\times\mathbf F$$
Is the definition of the torque $\boldsymbol\tau$ of a force $\mathbf F$ that is applied at position $\mathbf r$ relative to some "reference point" (where $\mathbf r=0$).

The equation
$$\boldsymbol\tau=I\boldsymbol\alpha$$

Is an analog of Newton's second law ($\mathbf F=m\mathbf a$). Therefore, in this equation $\boldsymbol\tau$ represents the *net* torque $\sum_i\boldsymbol\tau_i$.

> Is the torque at a point by a force is equal to torque of the whole body?

This question is not very clear. But I think I can still help based on what we have defined above. If you have a body with a set of forces $\mathbf F_i$ acting on it, you can determine the torque $\boldsymbol\tau_i=\mathbf r_i\times\mathbf F_i$ about some point$^*$ for each of the forces. Then you can find the net torque acting on the body by adding up all of these torques. $\sum_i\boldsymbol\tau_i=I\boldsymbol\alpha$

---

$^*$ You can choose any point you want, but some points are better than others depending on the analysis you want to do on your system.

Comment: I agree,  but you should add the caveat that $\boldsymbol{\tau}= I \boldsymbol{\alpha}$  is not correct, but instead $$\boldsymbol{\tau} = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \left( \mathbf{I} \boldsymbol{\omega} \right) = \mathbf{I} \boldsymbol{\alpha} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{I} \boldsymbol{\omega} $$

Comment: @ja72 Yes,thank you. It looks like the OP is at an intro-physics level where $\mathbf I\boldsymbol\omega$ is parallel to $\boldsymbol\omega$, so I decided not to go into all of that. If you want to post an answer covering that though you can.

Comment: Agree, although the _op_ used `\boldsymbol` which indicates a vector quantities. I understand.

Comment: @ja72 Actually that was me (look at the edit history). Even in the specific cases of introductory physics they are still technically vectors, which is why I did it.